# PycURLLibrary can not load module pycurl while console python can

Tags: python, maven, robotframework, pycurl

I'm trying to run some [robot tests](http://robotframework.org/) using python 2.7 and curl on ubuntu 16.04.
This requires the python module "robotframework-pycurllibrary", which itself uses pycurl.

Howver, when starting the tests I get the following error:

```
Error in file ...: Importing test library 'PycURLLibrary' failed: ImportError: No module named pycurl
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PycURLLibrary/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    import pycurl
```

But when I run python in console, I can import pycurl itself, as well as PycURLLibrary.
Now first thing I thought of was include paths of course, but after dozens of trys, I somehow doubt it to be the problem.

Any of you any idea? Ever seen something similar?

Comment: It sounds like robot and the console are using different values for PYTHONPATH.

Comment: If you are using a runner script that activates a virtualenv, that would explain it. Same thing as Bryan said, essentially.